# python urllib2.URLError handling

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm extracting live feed from a webpage in json. The page updates every minute so I would extract the data every minute. But the server of that webpage is sometimes not very stable and my code stops running. I want to write it in a way that my code will constantly requesting for data until it gets it. Someone wrote something like this before:

```
try: 
    f=urllib2.open(blablabla...)

except urllib2.HTTPError, detail:
    if detail.error == 500:
      time.sleep(1)
      continue
    else:
      raise
```

But my code still stops running with this error: 
urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2.HTTPError` is a subtype of `urllib2.URLError`. So when `open` raises an `URLError`, you don’t actually catch that when just looking for `HTTPError`s. If you want to catch `URLError`s too, add another `except` clause to handle it.